# iOS Autolayout issue, Adding login view looks bad (image inside)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm adding a login view in my tableview. But as you can see on the image below it doesn't look great.

I am using auto layout for both the tableview and the loginview.

For the loginview I have the constraints showed on the image below, but what's strange(to me) is that these constraints seem to be valid for both the Green View and its superview (the black). Because, when I change it for one of them, it changes for the other as well.

Note: The loginview has separate a controller, but the controller is not presented. The loginview is just added to the tableview.

Any suggestions?
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add constraints that constrain the loginView to be the same size as the table view. Do this when you add the subview

Comment: Jack, could you give an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in this image, there are 4(!) views you need to account for. 
1.) the superview
2.) the UITableview
3.) the black view
4.) the login-view (blue-green?)

It looks like the constraints for (4) are set correctly in relation to (3)

To me, I'd examine the constraints for (3) in relation to (1).

In other words make sure the leading/trailing top/bottom constraints are all 0 or to margin in relation to the superview, and you should be good to go.

Comment: If i set the constraints to 0, the greenish view just expands to the black area, and nothing more. It's as if the black and green are the same view.

Comment: My guess is you'll want to set the constraints on the black area in relation to the superview. Setting the constraints of the green to 0 in relation to the black would naturally cover the black with the green...

Comment: If you attach a screenshot of the view hierarchy, it would give us a better sense of how things are nested

Comment: How do i set the constants "In relation to the superview"?? adding image

Comment: Next question: I can see View(1)-View(2, where the login items live). Is there ANOTHER view where the UITable is?

Comment: Also, For View (1)... Have you set constraints? You might do what you need to do by PINNING View 1 to top/bottom left/right etc.

Comment: what is actually meant by "superview" in this context? the UIViewController's view?

Comment: Superview is typically the whole VC yes. I'm going to bet the View 1 (the black one) is the offending one. the View 2 (green one) is correctly set to space/size itself in relation to View 1. View 1 now needs to be set in relationship to the UIVC (the superview). Presumably, there's another view hierarchy containing the UItableview, yes?

Comment: YES that sounds correct, the UITableview is embedded in a NavigationController which is embedded in a UITabBarController. Can i do that in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example on how you could implement this. This assumes you are using view controller containment, which you should be.

`child` is your signIn view and `self` is the Table view controller

```
 // Add login view to my view
[self addChildViewController:child];
child.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:child.view];
[child didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// Add constraints
NSDictionary * views = @{@"view" : child.view, @"super" : self.view};

NSArray * hConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[view]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray * vConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[view]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

[self.view addConstraints: [hConstraints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:vConstraints]];
```

Comment: This actually did it!!!, now the textfield and banana just needs to be centered int the green view.. how would i go about a that?

Comment: You can set constraints to center those in the Storyboard. If you need help on that, post a new screenshot on what it looks like now

Comment: I will add image now, I have another question - It would actually be better for the loginview to attach to self.view.window, because, as it is now, the tableview can still scroll with the loginview on top. I tried changing 1 line to [self.view.window addSub....], but that fails